# accessing files via python using a service account

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu-16.04, pywin32

I am playing with windows server 2012 r2.
I have some files on the server. I have a separate service account which has the read access to the files. What i want to do is using python access the files by network share(any other suggestions welcomed) but only through the service account.

PS: i cannot use RDP.

Comment: So, i have used 
command = "net use /user:" + USER + " " + REPOSITORY_PATH + " " + PASS.. 

and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying *WINAPI*s for this task are part of [[MS.Docs]: WNetAddConnection2W function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2w) family.

The [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) wrapper is [[ActiveState]: Module win32wnet](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32wnet.html) (it's not the official doc (I couldn't find any at this point) - I don't know for how long the *URL* will be valid, but it's the best I could find).

I've prepared a trivial example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import pywintypes
import win32wnet


CONNECT_INTERACTIVE = 0x00000008

HOST_NAME = "192.168.1.3"
SHARE_NAME = "Work"
SHARE_FULL_NAME = os.path.sep * 2 + os.path.sep.join((HOST_NAME, SHARE_NAME))
SHARE_USER = "cfati"
SHARE_PWD = "********"


def main():
    net_resource = win32wnet.NETRESOURCE()
    net_resource.lpRemoteName = SHARE_FULL_NAME
    flags = 0
    #flags |= CONNECT_INTERACTIVE
    print("Trying to create connection to: {:s}".format(SHARE_FULL_NAME))
    try:
        win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(net_resource, SHARE_PWD, SHARE_USER, flags)
    except pywintypes.error as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print("Success!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- The password is obfuscated (obviously)
- This is the simplest functionality (the equivalent of your command), however the function can do much more:

  - One thing that I want to point out. If you:

    - Input some invalid credentials, and
    - Decomment the `flags |= CONNECT_INTERACTIVE` line

    A credentials dialog box will then pop up

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050602112>net use
> New connections will be remembered.
>
> There are no entries in the list.
>
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050602112>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Trying to create connection to: \\192.168.1.3\Work
> Success!
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050602112>net use
> New connections will be remembered.
>
>
> Status       Local     Remote                    Network
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> OK                     \\192.168.1.3\Work        Microsoft Windows Network
> The command completed successfully.
>
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050602112>net use * /delete /y
> You have these remote connections:
>
>                     \\192.168.1.3\Work
> Continuing will cancel the connections.
>
> The command completed successfully.
>
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050602112>net use
> New connections will be remembered.
>
> There are no entries in the list.
> ```

Comment: Of course not. *pywin32* is *Win* specific. Also the question has the *windows* tag (nothing mentioned that would involve *Lnx*).

Comment: Any idea about the Linux version ?

Comment: This file sharing protocol is *Win* specific (*SMB* / *CIFS*). From *Lnx* it's available using *Samba*. I'm not aware how to access it from *Python* (whether there is a *pysmb* or similar module). But anyway, I think that could be the subject of a different question.